# Replace string values in array by multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array:
`array = ['wood', 'glass', 'metal', 'glass', 'glass', 'wood', 'metal', 'wood', 'glass', 'glass']`

and I want to replace each string by a condition, for example: each `'wood'` replace by `'blue'`, `'glass'` by `'red'` and `'metal'` by `'green'`.

so I get:
`['blue', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red']`

I'm trying to do something like:
`['red' if el == 'glass' for el in array]`

I don't know how to do multiple conditions or even if this method is the right thing to do?

please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create a dictionary:

```
dct = {'wood': 'blue', 'glass': 'red', 'metal': 'green'}
new_array = [dct[item] for item in array]
```

Comment: This won't work when `item` is not one of the keys.

Comment: @cicolus yes obviously. this was just a quick demonstration how to use dictionaries with a list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to map old value to new values.

Example:

```
>>> name_mapping = {'wood':'blue'}
>>> res = [name_mapping.get(el, el) for el in array]
>>> res
['blue', 'glass', 'metal', 'glass', 'glass', 'blue', 'metal', 'blue', 'glass', 'glass']
```

[dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) with keep the current element in the result in case the element is not a key of the mapping dictionary.